# What are the correct QCD Feynman diagrams for jets or hadronization?

Tags: feynman-diagrams, quantum-chromodynamics, hadronization

In many drawings for jets or hadronization there are outgoing individual quark or gluon lines from which hadrons seem to emerge. But this is wrong: a color-neutral hadron cannot emerge from a single quark or gluon line.

See e.g. page 7 in

[The Strong Interaction and LHC phenomenology; Juan Rojo; University of Oxford](https://www2.physics.ox.ac.uk/sites/default/files/2014-03-31/qcdgrad_rojo_oxford_tt14_1_intro_pdf_77815.pdf)

There is one process where a *color singulet* $t\bar{t}$ and eventually the final state on the right emerges from a  virtual gluon which is a *color octet*.

What is the correct description of these processes? Is it possible to do this in principle via Feynman diagrams, even if the calculations are too complex in practice?

Comment: What makes you think that $t\bar t$ is a color singlet? There is a singlet state there, but also an octet state. Regarding the final hadron state I thought the idea was that as the "final" partons in these diagrams get further apart from each other, you see QCD strings stretching between them, which eventually break and create quark-antiquark pairs which compensate the color charges of these "final" partons. I am no expert though and someone else should answer this.

Comment: If you look at the diagram on page 7 you can see that the final state of this t-t-bar-pair is a color singulet. That means that the t-t-bar-pair itself must be a color singulet. But that is in contradiction with the fact that the gluon is certainly not a color singulet. All diagrams I have seen are inconsistent with SU(3) color algebra. I am looking for a diagram that is consistent in that sense.

Comment: „as the partons in these diagrams get further apart from each other, you see QCD strings stretching between them, which eventually break and create quark-antiquark pairs ... “ Yes, that was my understanding as well. But the diagrams do not show something like that.